# 'Allow Large Results' option in Browser Tool is not honored

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to query a relatively small table (1.3M rows, 517MB) and do an `order by` on one of the columns. The results are configured to write to another table and "Allow Large Results" is checked. But BigQuery still gives the error:

```
Error: Response too large to return. Consider setting allowLargeResults to true in your job configuration. For more details, see https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/querying-data#largequeryresults
```

Example job: gdfp-7415:job_asEyhGwqdrCwllhxCOGGE5osHlE

Why is this not working?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't work:

```
SELECT *
FROM [wikipedia_benchmark.Wiki10M]

"Response too large to return."
```

This works:

```
SELECT *
FROM [wikipedia_benchmark.Wiki10M]
[x] Allow Large Results
```

This doesn't work:

```
SELECT *
FROM [wikipedia_benchmark.Wiki10M]
ORDER BY title
[x] Allow Large Results

"Response too large to return."
```

The problem is that you can not use 'ORDER BY' with 'Allow Large Results'. That's because "allow large results" distributes the output job, instead of collecting everything in one node. As output is distributed, there's no root node to run the sorting.

A clear problem here is that the error message is not clear about this. Sorry for that!